# How do I assign a created contact to the current user in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to create a contact which is pushed to the current user's array of contacts.

My controller currently only creates a contact generically and isn't specific to the user.

**Controller:**

```
function contactsCreate(req, res) {

  Contact
    .create(req.body)
    .then(contact => res.status(201).json(contact))
    .catch(() => res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong'}));
}
```

**Contact Model:**

```
const contactSchema = new Schema({

  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  job: String,
  address: String,
  number: Number
});
```

**User model:**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  passwordHash: { type: String, required: true },
  contacts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Contact' }]
});
```

Comment: It depends on how you're doing authentication.  Do you have access to the user info on the request like in passport?

Comment: I believe so, I'm using express-jwt and bcrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the username on the request object, something like this should work:

```
async function contactsCreate(req, res) {
  const username = request.User.username

  try {
      const newContact = await Contact.create(req.body)
      const user = await User.findOne({username})
      user.contacts.push(newContact)
      await user.save()
      return res.status(201).json(contact)
  } catch ( err ) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong'})
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tweaked your answer slightly below

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to LazyElephant above. The solution (tweaked) was:

```
async function contactsCreate(req, res) {
  const userId = req.user.id;

  try {
    const newContact = await Contact.create(req.body);
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    user.contacts.push(newContact);
    await user.save();
    return res.status(201).json(newContact);
  } catch ( err ) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong'});
  }
}
```